# Does an Indonesian citizen need a transit visa at Munich airport?

Tags: indonesian-citizens, muc, airport-terminals

I am UK citizen travelling from New Delhi to Munich on Lufthansa where I need to change planes and terminal to get a Condor flight to Agadir. The travel agent informed me that I must collect and check in bags again. I understand I do not need a Schengen visa to travel from T2 to T1.

However I am travelling with a friend from Indonesia.

Does he need pass Immigration to collect and recheck bags, and thus require a  visa?

Comment: Yes, you need a Schengen visa to collect and re-check bags, since you must pass immigration control in order to reach the baggage claim area.  Or rather, you do not need one, since you're from the UK, but your Indonesian friend needs one.  It might be possible for you to get your friend's bags (and your friend check in at a transfer desk without passing immigration), but I wouldn't count on it.  If you can check all the bags on your own ticket, though, you might be okay.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as his "transfer" is different - he needs to get through Schengen passport control and not merely transfer airside.

Comment: @GeorgeY. That situation is handled in point 2 of the accepted answer, "Can you transfer without leaving the international area of the airport?"

Comment: He has to leave the international area of the airport, because he has to collect the luggage. In MUC (as in any other European airport I've been to) luggage collection was always behind passport control.

Comment: @GeorgeY. right, so the answer to the point-two question is "yes," and the resulting instruction is, correctly: *If you have to leave the international area to make your transfer, you cannot transit without a visa and you need a full Schengen visa (and not merely an “airport transit visa”).*

Comment: I spoke to Condor and they said usually can check luggage in on Lufthansa and go all the way. Condor also said can get boarding pass in transit.

Comment: I don't want to make a mistake but as I understand it, my Indonesian friend does not need a transit visa in Germany. Also he does not need a schengen visa to move from T2 to T1 so should be OK?